# How do you put a blank underline in an Access (rich text) text box

Tags: forms, ms-access, underline

I need to include a blank line in a text box to hold a signature in an Access form. Flanking several space characters with `<u>      </u>` doesn't do it. I flanked another word in the text box with the `<u> </u>` and it worked fine. Typing several successive underscores doesn't look right (it's dashed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert some *divs*:

```
<div>Signed by:</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>____________________</div>
<div>Signer</div>
```

**Edit**: Two methods:

```
<div>Using font <font face="Microsoft Sans Serif" size=2>Microsoft Sans Serif 8:</font></div>

<div><font face="Microsoft Sans Serif" size=1>___________________________</font></div>

<div>&nbsp;</div>

<div>or <font face="Microsoft Sans Serif" size=2>Microsoft Sans Serif 24:</font></div>

<div><font face="Microsoft Sans Serif" size=6>____________</font></div>

<div>&nbsp;</div>

<div><font size=3>Using underline and an end-of-line marker:</font></div>

<div><u>                                                              &lt;</u></div>
```

Displays in Access 2016 like this:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't show in my original comment, but I tried the "<u>    </u>" method and it worked when a word was flanked by the html underline format markers but not when spaces were flanked. Also, as mentioned in the original, the repeated underscore method doesn't look right in my form. I also tried wrapping my repeated underscores with the html underline code and it still has gaps.

Comment: Hmm.. _Edge_ does it right - renders a continuous underscore.

Comment: Do you mean that when you flank several spaces with the u's you get a continuous underscore in Edge? Just to clarify I'm not in a browser, I'm filling out a (rich) text box on an Access report form. Again, the wrapping u's work on actual words but not on a string of spaces.

Comment: well, this is kind of wash now because when I set the box to rich text (to be able to use HTML), I lose the ability to set the line spacing in the text box. The properties say the line spacing is set as I want it (0.1"), but I when I view the print preview, the lines aren't spaced. If I switch back to Plain Text, the line-spacing is correct.

Comment: I still want to know why the repeated underscore technique produces gaps...maybe it has something to do with the selected font.

Comment: This doesn't quite do it because of the "<" at the end of the line, but your answer did lead me to a solution that results in a clean line without the "<" at the end. If you replace the line terminator "&lt" with "&#8202" (i.e. a hairspace), the entire string (long string of 32-type whitespace + 1 hairspace) is underlined. [wiki on whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character)

Comment: Thanks, couldn't find that whitespace character. That leaves two solutions, the first even with controllable line thickness.

Comment: I'm sorry Gustav, but there is a problem with both of those solutions. If you look closely, you'll see that each of those lines (thick and thin) is dashed. Usually it wouldn't matter that much and nobody would probably ever notice unless they were looking for it, but the fact remains...they're not continuous lines. The only solution discovered here that creates a continuous line (and no additional visible characters) is the "leading hairspace" technique.

Comment: Can't tell. As you can see from my appended screenshot, all lines are continuous on my screens - even tried on two different monitors.

Comment: You're right and I was mistaken. They are not dashed in the final result. I will go ahead and mark yours as the solution.

Comment: Ah, that sorted it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Appending a hairspace (character code 8202) to the end of a string of "regular" spaces (code 32) allows underlining the entire string of preceding spaces. Thanks to Gustav for opening the door to this solution.

Comment: 65279 (zero width non-breaking space) is probably the better choice.